# Loop not working when responded with Yes in Python

Tags: python

```py
keep_playing = "yes"

print("I can write and help you to study. What am I?")
print(" ")

guesses = 1
guess = input("What is your guess? ")

while keep_playing == "yes":
    secret_word = "pen"


    while guess.lower() != secret_word:
        print("Sorry, that's the wrong answer.")
        guess = input("What is your guess?: ")                
        guesses = guesses + 1
    if guess.lower()== secret_word :
        print("Congratulations! , You guessed it")
        print(f"It took you {guesses} guesses")
    
    keep_playing = input("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ")
print("See you next time! Thanks for playing.")
```

At the end of the game, when I responded with `YES`, It doesn't loop back to the beginning of the game. Still pretty new to this. May I know what the problem is?

I expect the game to loop to the beginning when the player type `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

**YES** and **yes** are different strings
Strings comparsion in python case sensitive

Change this:

```py
while keep_playing == "yes":
```

To this:

```py
while keep_playing.lower() == "yes":
```

So any answer like **YES** or **YeS** or **yEs** or ... will be converted to **yes** and compared with **yes**

Answer (score 1):

Where you state the problem is:

> At the end of the game, when I responded with YES. It doesn't loop back to the beginning of the game.

The problem is that after the user types "yes" you need to add some block of code to reinitialize your program's variables to reset `guess=""` and ask the user another question.

So where you currently have only:

```
     keep_playing = input("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ")
print("See you next time! Thanks for playing.")
```

you could change that to something like:

```
    keep_playing = input("Would you like to play again (yes/no)? ")
    if keep_playing.lower() == "yes":
        guess =  ""
        # <add more code here to reset your question,
        # the answer and the number of guesses>
    else: print("See you next time! Thanks for playing.")
```

That solves the SO question you asked about looping.  The task of working out code to add new questions is left open for you to solve.

Note @Mishin870 is correct about changing your main loop to test keep_playing.**lower()** which you will want to do if you want to allow the user type in either lower or upper case.  But the way I read it I believe you were asking why your program didn't appear to run again which is solved if you reinitialize your variables at the end as I've suggested.